# How to make a DAG that needs to process the data from today?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a DAG that starts at 7:30pm every day. It needs to process the files located in /data/yyyy-mm-dd/ directory. yyyy-mm-dd is that same day.

If I use execution_date + timedelta(day=1) it works when the DAG is ran by the scheduler. But this breaks when I use the backfill command (I have to give it 2019-01-01 to run for 2019-01-02)

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question sounds a little confused about the `execution_date` for backfills. The backfill command asks you to specify the alternate start and end dates to run the DAG in. It then uses the `schedule_interval` to figure out runs that would have run in that range and passes them their `execution_date`.

So, your `schedule_interval` probably looks like `30 19 * * *`. And as you know your run is passed the start of the interval at the closing of that interval, so a scheduled `execution_date` of 2019-01-01T19:30:00.000 will be triggered to start after 2019-01-02T19:30:00.000. It seems at that time you want the job to pick up data that landed in `/data/2019-01-02/` which is why you're adding a day to the `execution_date` and formatting it for the source.

If you're [backfill](https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#backfill)ing, it should behave the same way (rather than shifting time around). So given `-s 2019-01-01 -e 2019-01-02` it's going to backfill a run that would have been triggered after 2019-01-02T19:30:00.000 with the execution date of 2019-01-01T19:30:00.000 isn't it?

As for other ways to do this:

- You could move your runs to midnight and have them use the date in the `execution_date`. But 4.5h delay is probably not what you had in mind.
- You see if the data directories could be named differently, I doubt that would be okay if there's other people or jobs relying on them.
- Airflow also has a `next_execution_date`, which is basically going to give you the same result as adding a day to the `execution_date`. But you might like the formatted [macro](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/1.10.2/code.html#macros) `{{ next_ds }}` for your needs.

Comment: Hi Daniell, thank you for the detailed answer. I think this matches my mental model. The thing I don't like is this: to process the data for 2019-01-02 I have to run backfill with -s 2019-01-01. This is confusing and potentially error prone. 

One way I can imagine dealing with this is by detecting if I'm running on schedule or via backfill, but dag_run.external_trigger does not detect backfilled jobs.

Comment: @boriska It's a hack, but… theo operators' `context`'s `TaskInstance` can get it's own `DagRun` which can get it's own `run_id` (or use the property `is_backfill`). Scheduled runs start with `"scheduled__"`, Manual triggered ones with `"manual__"` and backfill jobs with `"backfill_"`